# Suggestion on documenting endpoints for a Python Bottle web service

Tags: python, rest, bottle, documentation-generation

I have a portion of my API that i am exposing using Bottle (http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html).

I am now looking to document these endpoints for the end user clients and am looking for a good solution. I am looking for something that is tightly integrated with my"routes" defined in the Bottle app so that any changes in the future keep in sync. The key areas i want to document are the HTTP method types that are accepted and the necessary query parameters.

I have included an example route below which queries whether an instance defined in the underlying API is online. As you can see the route only accepts GET requests, and the "check_valid_instance" function expects to find a query parameter. Looking at this route definition there is no indication that a query param is needed and that is what i am trying to add here! Both to the source code, and also externally to some type of help page

`@app.route("/application/app_instance/is_instance_online", method="GET")
    def is_instance_online():
    _check_valid_instance()
    function = eval("app_instance.is_instance_online")
    return _process_request_for_function(function)`

The above route would be called as following

```
http://IP:Port/applicaton/app_instance/is_instance_online?instance=instance_name
```

Any suggestions welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: u can use like @route ('/application/app_instance/is_instance_online/param1=:param1&param2=:param2', method='GET') i dont know whether the wildcard ? can be used

Answer (score 0):

For additional params you can create a structure similar to this:

```
COMMANDS = {'is_instance_online': {'mandatory_params': 'instance_name', 
                                   'description': 'command description'}}

self.bottle.route('/<command>', method='GET', commands=COMMANDS)(self.command_execute)
```

Then you should be able to generate JSON description of the whole API as shown below:
[Automatic Generation of REST API description with json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412784/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-generate-rest-api-json-description-from-bottle-r/27450345#27450345)